# What does this Xcode link warning mean? can't add line info to anonymous symbol

Tags: xcode

I am working towards getting rid of all link warnings, but I am getting three that I don't quite understand and a google search for this warning hasn't been helpful.

The output to Xcode looks like:

ld: warning: can't add line info to anonymous symbol __ZN16CLineAlignWidgetD0Ev.lsda from /path/to/CLineAlignWidget.o

What causes this warning and what can be done to fix it?

I have looked at the CLineAlignWidget class and it looks like other classes which aren't generating this warning.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the llvm IRC channel and asked this question and got back the following response:

d0k: It's a compiler bug, but I think it's harmless